# Agregar columna en un MDX para SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs

Necesito a esta consulta MDX, agregar una columna con los valores de Provincias.

```
    select non empty STRTOSET(@Organizacion,CONSTRAINED) on rows, --Parametro para SSRS
{    [Measures].[Adeuda Informar]

} on columns
FROM [Modelo]
```

Este seria el resultado que necesito.

[image: Este seria el resultado que necesito, manteniendo el parametro]